# jQuery mouseleave getting triggered on using scroll bar and right clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

jQuery mouseleave is getting triggered on right click in Chrome v41. This is not happening in Firefox.

Also mouseleave is getting triggered when using scroll bar in windows, again the problem doesn't exist in Firefox.

Is there something that needs to be taken care for Chrome?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please do comment if more information is necessary.

This is how I am triggering the event.

```
$("body").on("mouseleave", function(){
     alert();
});
```

Comment: Being able to see your code would help a lot here.

Comment: Updated the question with the code. Please check.

Comment: Still wondering why the question is down voted.

Comment: Looks like a Chrome bug. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=450138

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a bug. Why would Firefox behaviour would be the expected one ? I mean, it makes sense that the mouseleave event is beeing triggered in that case.

Comment: Scrollbar is logical but the response on right click in Chrome (alerting before showing menu) seems odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a fix to your problem. Checkout this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SukanyaHalder/r0m0mcdx/2/).

```
$("body").on("mousedown", function(e){
    if(e.which==3) 
    {
        $(this).addClass("right");
        console.log("From Right Click");
    }
}).on("mouseleave", function(e){
    if($(this).hasClass("right"))
    {
        console.log("it is right clicked");
        $(this).removeClass("right");  
        return;
    }
    alert();
     $(this).removeClass("right");  
     console.log(e.which+"From Mouseleave");
});
```

I have attached `mousedown` event with body which adds a class to the body when it is right clicked. `mouseleave` is called after `mouseout` in this example, so it checks if the class is still attached to the body. If true then it doesn't show any alert. (It is a fix not a solution :( )

Comment: When you right click and then `mouseleave` it cannot be captured. I have updated the fiddle. It was showing `From Right Click` because if you click it `mousedown` will fire. I forgot to put the `console.log` in `if` clause

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by checking the mouse position when the mouseleave event is triggered.

In my case, I only wanted the event to trigger if the mouse went above the document so I just checked the Y position of the mouse was < 0.

This also stops the event from triggering when the right mouse button is clicked.

Full details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29966853/2347456

Comment: Yes, that's right. But this will need the browser to calculate the Y position for every mouse move which will cost GPU again.